# best practice mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below.

**Attendance Table: emp_attendance**
 id,emp_id,attendance_date,status

**Attendance Table: emp_leaves**
 id,emp_id,leave_from_date,leave_to_date,leave_type

What is the best way to join these two tables using emp_id? Incase if the emp_leaves table has more than one record for the same emp_id  then the join will return two rows in the query results, this is what i have tried.

```
SELECT emp_attendance.emp_id, emp_attendance.attendance_date,
CASE 
WHEN emp_attendance.attendance_date BETWEEN emp_leaves.leave_from_date AND emp_leaves.leave_to_date 
THEN emp_leaves.leave_type ELSE emp_attendance.Status end AS final_Status 
FROM emp_attendance LEFT JOIN emp_leaves 
ON emp_leaves.emp_id = emp_attendance.emp_id
```

kindly advice.

Comment: what do you mean by "best practice to join"? The only point I can see here is that to fulfill the requirement "ncase if the emp_leaves table has more than one record for the same emp_id then the join will return two rows in the query results", you can just use standard JOIN, which results in better performances but leaves out rows with no emp_leaves.

Comment: It's behaving correctly.  It all depends on what you want. If you have more than one records in emp_leaves for the same emp_id, of course it will return more than one record.

Comment: You could union the tables instead of joining them assuming a leave an attendance don't overlap.  or you could get the ,most recent leave record instead of all; but as other indicated.  This lacks a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to identify your issue you're looking for help with.  Sample data expected results help!

Comment: @Eric, sorry for not making the question clearer. I agree it is behaving correctly. Can you please suggest some method where we can omit the multiple result for same emp_id for same attendance_date after joining those two tables

Comment: @xQbert, I will have to create a new table for leaves something like this with thee fields, emp_id,attendance_date,leave_type, then I can union them or I can easily join them.

Comment: It depends on what you want really.  I can't help you unless I know what you want.  Why do you want to join them?  What do you actually want to accomplish?  emp_leaves can have multiple records.  Which record do you want to get if there are multiple.

Comment: @davidb no, I'd just duplicate attendance_date twice so you have a from to with the same value.

Comment: @xQbert, i think i should have a daywise table to overcome this issue. i have posted a new question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490612/mysql-get-dates-between-two-dates